# Where does my friend live? 4

Tags: knowledge, geography

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

My friend, Sev, sent me some clues to tell where he is:

> Hinder, order, tales, existence, diary, razor, THREE

Using these clues, I could figure out where he is. **Can you get the answer?**

Comment: Damn this is hard! So far I have: Bpxunzf ENMBE, naq Pnagreohel GNYRF, guvf uvagf ng gur rnfgrea pbhagvrf bs gur HX. Fvapr Bpxunz vf va Fheerl naq Pnagreohel vf va Xrag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well well well...

First of all shout out to primenumbah for working out the theme.

> If you look at the 7 new wonders of the world you have The Great wall of China in China, Petra in Jordan, The Colosseum in Italy, Chichen Itza in Mexico, Taj Mahal in India, Christ the Redeemer in Brazil and Macchu Picchu in Peru.

Then:

> If you look at the first 3 (Hence the clue THREE) letters of each clue you have HIN, ORD, TAL, EXI, DIA, RAZ, these three letters, Are three letters in China, Jordan, Italy, Mexico, India and Brazil.

And so:

> The one missing out is Macchu Picchu in Peru where your friend must be.

Comment: ,Aaah nice job!

Answer (score 1):

I think your friend is in

> Giza, Egypt

Hinder

> A synonym for *block*. The pyramids consists of stone blocks.

Order

> One interpretation of the word order is to *arrange*. The stones were arranged in a specific way.

Tales

> There are many **tales** or stories written in hieroglyph on the stones of the pyramids.

Existence

> This word, I believe, has to do with preserving the **existence** of the dead pharoas (mummiefied), which are said to be inside the pyramids.

Diary

> This refers to the "**Diary** of Merer" that record the daily activity of stone transportations to Giza.

Razor

> Is a synonym for "cutting edge". The stones of the pyramids were "cut" or carved with precise precision.

Three

> The most famous pyramids are well-known as the **Three** pyramids of Giza.

And maybe

> Your friend is named after the number seven, which refer to the *seven* wonders of the world in which the pyramids of Giza is one of them.

Comment: These connections feel very tenuous; if this is the intended answer, then the puzzle could use some serious improvement.